# How to get it so it fill_between gets all the area until y reaches 0 instead of just filling instances where there are multiple values of y=1

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I want to almost create something similar to a trigger as if it was sql where in the graph, the shading starts when y=1 and then stops shading where y=0. Then repeat that sequence for the remainder of the graph. For the current code, it looks like it just shades when there are multiple instances of y equaling 1, which would make sense with the output I have right now. Photo of output is shown as well.[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2QVz.png)

```
ax = df_merge.plot(kind='scatter', x='OPTY_CLOSE_DATE', y='REVENUE_STATUS_FLAG')
ax.fill_between(df_merge['OPTY_CLOSE_DATE'], 0, df_merge['REVENUE_STATUS_FLAG'], where=df_merge['REVENUE_STATUS_FLAG']==1, alpha=0.4,)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace your `fill_between` line with

```
ax.fill_between(df_merge['OPTY_CLOSE_DATE'], df_merge['REVENUE_STATUS_FLAG'], step='post', alpha=0.4)
```

The `step` parameter defines where the "trigger" should start. For more info, look at the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html#matplotlib-pyplot-fill-between).

### Result

As expected, fill area starts where y = 1 and stops where y = 0.

[image]